# Big Tryout On the Way

Tags: soccer

I have my first college tryout coming up and I'm very nervous, I'm a center midfielder and I play soccer, What can I do to boost my explosiveness in my running and how can I make my touch better (please don't just suggest juggling, i can hit 400-700 consistently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am speaking from experience, as someone who tried out for their college team, and who knows many college players from multiple universities. The one thing that will separate this tryout from anything you have done before is the volume of running. The tryout will have running to start, running in the middle, and running to finish. Not jogging; running and sprinting. Someone who can juggle hundreds of times probably has plenty of touch, but do you have the fitness to retain that touch at the end of the day?

So, work on your fitness. Do shuttle runs; 40 yard sprints with the ball. Then do them again. And again. And again. Then go play in a scrimage, and finish that off with more running. Also, be prepared for multiple mile distances. Run mostly in you cleats on the grass.

Make sure your shoes are broken in. I think more people dropped out of my tryout because of blisters than anything else.

BTW, I didn't make my team, even though I am convinced that I had the skill for it. But by the end of a week of 2 a days, I was crushed by the running load. Learn from my mistake, good luck, and let us know how you do.